# Converting a column to Numeric but it still shows as float with .0 value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a column to int, so i don't have 0 in front of the number and .0 after the number.
this is what i am using

```
data['ID'] = pd.to_numeric(data['ID'], errors='coerce')
```

but it is not converting the column type

here is image what it looks like.

[image]

Please if you can help

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the NaNs that are of float type.

You can use `fillna` to make the NaNs 0:

```
data['ID'] = pd.to_numeric(data['ID'], errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Or to keep the NaN as the new integer NA, use `convert_dtypes`:

```
data['ID'] = pd.to_numeric(data['ID'], errors='coerce').convert_dtypes()
```